# ASP.NET Core MVC - Image is not getting uploaded in live website directory

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I have my ASP.NET Core MVC website on production server of godaddy windows hosting. I have a "Create article" page which allows to select an image from PC and upload it in the project folder directory.

This functionality works fine on local server, but it doesn't work on production server. I have tried to change the upload path of the image multiple times, but none of them works for me. I get an error on production. If I don't upload the image and create article without it, it works fine on the production.

Paths which I have tried :

```
public static string ArticleImgPath = @"\images\Articles\";
public static string ArticleImgPath = "/images/Articles/";
public static string ArticleImgPath = "https://derawala.org/wwwroot/images/Articles/";
public static string ArticleImgPath = "https://derawala.org/httpdocs/wwwroot/images/Articles/";
public static string ArticleImgPath = "https://derawala.org/images/Articles/";
```

This is the error I got on production :

[image]

If I remove the image uploading code, I don't get any errors and the app works just fine.

I have also made sure to upload `appsettings.production.json` file to make sure that environment variables are set for production environment. Also, all the other functionalities of website including database operations work properly except those which have file uploading in it.

Here is my controller method for article creation:

```
public IActionResult ArticlePost(ParentForApply ParentVM)
{
    var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

    if (files.Count == 0)
    {
        ParentVM.ArticleModel.Img ="defltimg.png";

        _db.Articles.Add(ParentVM.ArticleModel);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return View(ParentVM);
    }
    else
    {
        string upload = WC.ArticleImgPath;
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);
        string fullpath = upload + fileName + extension;

        using (var filestream = new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            files[0].CopyTo(filestream);
        }

        ParentVM.ArticleModel.Img = fileName + extension;

        _db.Articles.Add(ParentVM.ArticleModel);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return View(ParentVM);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you swap to development environment to get detailed errors,not means you are not in production enviroment

Alos,you could read this document related with uploading files:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0

you could try with the codes in this document to upload file and store the content into database:

```
public class AppFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

in controller:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await FileUpload.FormFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

        // Upload the file if less than 2 MB
        if (memoryStream.Length < 2097152)
        {
            var file = new AppFile()
            {
                Content = memoryStream.ToArray()
            };

            _dbContext.File.Add(file);

            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("File", "The file is too large.");
        }
```

**Update**:
Could you swap to development environment to see the detailed error message?
Have you tried to write the path with WebRootPath?

```
public IActionResult New([FromServices]IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   ......
   using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "...."), FileMode.CreateNew))
  .....
}
```

Comment: Actually I am not adding the file into the database. I want to creata a file in a directory and just store the name of the image file into the database.

Comment: your solution works for local server. It doesn't work in production. 

Comment: I've Updated my answer,please check it

Comment: Actually the problem was with the access permissions to the directory of my hosted website. I have granted the essential permissions and it worked for me. BTW thank you for your support 

Answer (score 0):

I did solve with this way.

1. Login on cPanel
2. Go to File Manager and select the folder where you saved your image
3. Give the full control to this folder
4. Enjoy the image uploading now.